# Developing a very nonstandard Drupal form

Tags: forms, drupal-6

I'm creating a site for a local retail shop using Drupal.  Everything's been going very smoothly up until this current bit.

It's a comic shop, and I want to make a place where people can manage their own subscriptions.  Since the number of different titles a customer subscribes to can vary pretty widely, I want a way to make a completely dynamic form, with people able to add as many new lines as they need and I'm really struggling with Drupal's documentation.

Essentially, I'd like the final version of the page to look something like this:  http://www.monksp.org/foo.html

Anyone have any experience building a drupal form like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not achieve something similar using Taxonomy and free tagging? Take a look at http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/taxonomy

So in theory you would have a content type called "Subscription", each user would only be able to create one node of this type, it would have the taxonomy applied to it. The user can then edit the node and add more subscriptions. The great thing about this is that you can also use auto-complete. So say a user is already subscribed to X-Men another user can edit their subscription and start typing "X" this would then auto populate with suggested terms already in the taxonomy. e.g:

X-men: Origins
X-men: Apocalypse Saga
X-men: Noir

I think this is the functionality you've described.